# Random Three Clicking Sound

Tags: windows-7, audio, mouse-click

This has been an issue I have heard myself and from others for over a year now. At seemingly completely random times of the day while I have headphone in I can hear a three mouse clicking sounds. Always three fast clicks. I do only notice it while listening to music or watching a YouTube video but those are the only times I have headphones in.

Computers are all linked to shared drives and we have had issues before. This issue was re-brought to my attention today. Someone recently got a new computer. No more than a week ago. They had noticed the problem before the new computer and now are noticing it again on the new one. They asked me what it could be and I have no idea.

I have searched online and run malwarebytes. We have antivirus and a pretty hefty firewall, which means nothing if people open something they shouldn't.

Has anyone else noticed this? Anyone know what this could be. Its not a issue as far as being annoying, just more curious what it could be.

Specs: Office Use is Universal
Windows 7,
Chrome,
I use Rdio, Most use Spotify,
Skype,
Office 2013,
Filezilla,
Adobe CC,
Dropbox,
McAfee

Of-course id be more than happy to share more or run any test if you think it would help. More or less curious behind the culprit.

Comment: Sounds like it could be adware/spyware running in the background, or for a less malicious hypothesis, maybe just a broken keyboard/mouse.  It may be worth running a quick check with Spybot S&D (or another comparable program), just to eliminate the first prospect.

Comment: Try disabling the "Start Navigation" sound in Windows and see if that helps, if so, it's most likely a web page (or something) causing your browser to redirect/refresh.

Comment: SO i did run spybot sd and malwarebytes. Looks clean there. I also turned off the start navigation sounds in Explorer. So we shall see if it resurfaces.